# Is there a function to return all the multisite names?

Tags: multi-sites

Is there a Drupal function to return all the multisite names?

I have searched a bit but have not come up with anything.

Comment: Are you talking about domain access? What is a multisite name for you?

Comment: I mean if I have sites/foo.com and sites/example.com, it would return array('foo.com', 'example.com').

Comment: ok, I'm not sure there's something built for this

Comment: each instance of drupal isn't necessarily aware of other instances. You could write a custom module that does a simple directory search under sites to return the values you want.

Comment: Thanks guys, I came up with a not so elegant solution that I will post as an answer for now.

Comment: There would (should?) not be an easy method in the Drupal API to do this, because multi-site instances are not supposed to be aware of each other. That said... I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but perhaps you could make it a requirement that the developer adds a sites.php file (see [example.sites.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites!example.sites.php/7)) and parse that file.

Comment: In my testing so far sites.php gets loaded after drushrc.php. But yeah, I am trying to get drush to look in a sites/{sitename}/drush/ folder to load drushrc.php, aliases and commands per multisite.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is what I am using for now in a drushrc.php file. If you can improve upon this please post a new answer. Thanks

```
// Gets a list of all directories in /sites.
$sites = glob(drush_locate_root() . '/sites/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
// Strips the absolute path except for the last name.
$sites = array_map('basename', $sites);
// Removes the 'all' folder.
$sites = array_diff($sites, array('all'));
```

Comment: I like this solution but have replaced `drush_locate_root()` with `DRUPAL_ROOT`. It is set in index.php as the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution inspired by some team members and @marcvangend.

```
if (is_file(__DIR__ . '/../../sites.php')) {
  include __DIR__ . '/../../sites.php';
  $sites = array_keys($multisites);
  $sites[] = 'default';
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why do you need to do that? Why do you need the list of sites inside Drupal?

Comment: To make Drush look in a sites/{sitename}/drush/ folder for ../drush/commands, ../drush/aliases and ../drush/drushrc.php files.

Comment: This supposes that the project makes use of the sites.php file for multisite aliasing. As a side note, the default variable name in sites.php is `$sites`.