# How to programmatically check in module if multisite is used?

Tags: 8, multi-sites

Is it possible to easily check with code if a site is running as multisite instance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically get current multi-site instance name](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/257325/programmatically-get-current-multi-site-instance-name)

Comment: With the linked answer simply check if `$site_name !== 'default'`.

Comment: Couldn't 'default' site be there along the other ones?

Comment: Actually I just accidentally found this: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/123141/is-there-a-function-to-return-all-the-multisite-names which seems to be a proper duplicate.

Comment: Is a little bit unclear what you really need. So, you want to check if there are other instances then just "default", yeah then it seems to be a good idea to check the `sites.php` file or other directories within `/sites`.

Comment: More than _running as multi-site instance_, it should be _has been set as multi-site instance_. To me, _running as multi-site instance_ means _check if there are other multi-site instances running_. If the purpose is checking if a site has been set as multi-site instance, then what said from @leymannx is the direction to follow.

Comment: Also, the answers for https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/123141/is-there-a-function-to-return-all-the-multisite-names just help to find the list of multi-site instance names, but it doesn't help to find if the code is running for a multi-site instance, as in Drupal you can have multi-site instances and single-site instances.